# A Diagonalizable matrix must be diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $A \in M_{2×2}(\mathbb R)$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$. Show that if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ must be diagonal.

My idea is that let 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\
                   c&d \end{pmatrix},$$
then we want to show that $b=c=0$ and we also know that the characteristic polynomial is $$(t-\lambda)^2.$$

What could I do next?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ of $n\times n$ is diagonalizable if there exists $P$ non-singular ($PP^{-1}=P^{-1}P=I$) such that $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal and in the diagonal it contains the eigenvalues of $A$. If $\lambda$ is of multiplicity $n$, then $D=\lambda I$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: To be diagonalizable does not imply that an orthogonal diagonalization exists.

Comment: @leonbloy My bad. Thanks for point that out (I had in my head the result for symmetric matrices). I'll correct it. But it still works if I change to $P^{-1}$, doesn't it?

Comment: @RLC Yes that's correct.

Comment: thank you! I have understood!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: start assuming that $\lambda=1$. What matrix $B$ is $A$ similar to? From the formula 
$$A=P^{-1}BP,$$ 
where $P$ is some invertible matrix, conclude that $A=B$.

For the general case, consider the matrix 
$$
A':=\frac1{\lambda} A, $$ 
and apply the previous reasoning to it.

Of course this does not work when $\lambda=0$. What is the matrix $A$ in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the characteristic polynomial isn’t much help since $A$ would have the same characteristic polynomial if it weren’t diagonalizable. However, if $A$ is diagonalizable, and has only the repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$, then its minimal polynomial is $x-\lambda$, which means that $A-\lambda I=0$.

Here’s another proof: If $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$ and is diagonalizable, then there exists some invertible matrix such that $P^{-1}AP=\lambda I$. Then $$A = P(\lambda I)P^{-1} = \lambda(PP^{-1}) = \lambda I.$$